# Symfony Progress Bar is being recreated on new lines

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

The Symfony Console progress bar is not advancing on the same line but is rather being created on a new line

```
 1/2 [==============>-------------]  50%
 ! [NOTE] No changes made to Categories/CategoriesSchema              


 2/2 [============================] 100%
 2/2 [============================] 100%
```

I was under the assumption the progress bar will simply just move on the same line until the operation is complete. This is my code

```
$io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
$progressbar = new ProgressBar($output, count($elements));
$progressbar->start();

foreach ($elements as $element) {

     //work on element
     io->note("No changes made to ".ucfirst($name));

     $progressbar->advance();
     $io->newLine();
}

$progressbar->finish();
```

What I'm I doing wrong??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The progress advancement will always be on a new line if it is not autonomous, unless you clear it prior to writing to the io. [[sic]](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html#customizing-the-progress-bar)

> If you want to output something while the progress bar is running,
>   call [clear()](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.html#method_clear) first. After you're done, call [display()](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.html#method_display) to show the
>   progress bar again.

So either write to your io prior to starting the progress bar.

```
$io->note('No changes made to ' . ucfirst($name));
$io->newLine();

$progressbar->start();
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $progressbar->advance();
    sleep(1);
}
$progressbar->finish();
```

or call `clear()` on the progress bar prior to writing to the io and call `display()` when finished.

```
$progressbar->start();
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if (true /* put conditional here */) {
        $progressbar->clear(); //remove progress bar from display
        $io->note('No changes made to ' . ucfirst($name));
        $io->newLine();
        $progressbar->display(); //redraw progress bar in display
    }
    $progressbar->advance(); //move up a step
    sleep(1);
}    
$progressbar->finish();
```